# Seaching pattern to remove not needed layouts for viewgroup subclasses

Tags: android, android-layout

Given I want some subclassing of a LinearLayout like this:

```
public class MyLayout extends LinearLayout {

    public int someState=0;

    public ListViewHeadView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        View.inflate(context, R.layout.some_layout, this);
    }

    // more code here
}
```

with some_layout like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
                style="@style/textStyle"
                android:id="@+id/someTextView"/>

        <Button
                style="@style/buttonStyle"
                android:id="@+id/someButton"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

this works fine, but I have one LinearLayout to much which costs performance. The only way I see at the moment to remove the unneeded LinearLayout is to use a `<merge>` inside the xml instead of the LinearLayout. But then I would have to do a setOrientation in my code which I would love to see in an xml ( once - not at all usages ).
Can somebody point me to a pattern on how to do this nicely? If I do not have a state I can use the decorator-pattern and just decorate the LinearLayout with the functions I need - but when I need a state in this Layout I see no good way yet. Any hints and best practices welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd define the `android:orientation` attribute in your project's `attrs.xml` for your custom `ViewGroup` and add some code to evaluate this in the `ViewGroup`s constructor.

Comment: How does this prevent dual LinearLayouts (or one LL and one superfluous ViewGroup)?

Comment: My answer was not about on the decision whether or not to use a custom `ViewGroup` together with a `<merge>` layout. It was about how to prevent configuring the base class, a `LinearLayout` in this case, in the derived class, but keep the whole thing configurable via XML.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the uses of the `<merge>` element. Put it as the root in your XML file in place of the `<LinearLayout>`

The orientation can then be set whenever you use your custom view using `<com.example.MyView ... android:orientation="....">`
Or in code with `setOrientation`

If the orientation is always the same for this customs view, you can override set orientation and not call the super or something to that effect

Answer (score -1):

Define a stylable attribute and provide the orientation through the style

attr.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="MyLayout">
        <attr name="myLayoutStyle" format="reference"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

style.xml

```
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/main_background</item>
        <item name="myLayoutStyle">@style/MyLayoutStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyLayoutStyle" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:orientation">vertical</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Then in your constructor:

```
public class MyLayout extends LinearLayout {

    public int someState=0;

    public ListViewHeadView(Context context) {
         super(context, null, R.attr.MyLayoutStyle)
        View.inflate(context, R.layout.some_layout, this);
    }

    // more code here
}
```

In the constructor the reference is to the Stylable, not the style

Solution adapted from:

http://trickyandroid.com/protip-inflating-layout-for-your-custom-view/