# Any way to create an XML-and-code-behind-backed custom view on Android without superfluous ViewGroups?

Tags: android

I have adopted a pattern for creating custom views based on [these instructions](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html). I.e. I extend an existing ViewGroup, most often `FrameLayout` or `LinearLayout`, then I inflate my inner components from a layout XML file and then extend the class with whatever custom code I need in the code behind. Example:

**Layout file**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Status:"/>
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="5" android:id="@+id/status_text"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Code behind**:

```
public class SomeCustomView extends LinearLayout {
    public SomeCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.setOrientation(VERTICAL);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_some_custom, this, true);
    }

    public void setStatus(int statusCode) {
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.status_text)).setText("" + statusCode);
    }
}
```

The advantages to such an approach are primarily:

1. You get a good starting point with predefined layouts such as FrameLayout or LinearLayout. No drawing or layout code has to be implemented.
2. You can still use the visual editor of the IDE to compose the layout of the custom view.
3. All design is in XML, not Java

Yet there is a one major problem with this approach:

- You get *two* nested LinearLayouts* in this example, while I only need one. This is both a runtime cost and a design cost

*) To explain: When you implement this custom view in a parent view by refrering `SomeCustomView` either in XML or in code, you will get a) the LinearLayout of the class itself wrapping b) the LinearLayout defined in the XML.

So is there any way to eliminate the drawback without taxing on the benefits?

Comment: check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23747724/seaching-pattern-to-remove-not-needed-layouts-for-viewgroup-subclasses

Comment: The <merge> approach was interesting, but this will stop the IDE designer from rendering the subviews as LinearLayout. Defining attributes in attrs.xml doesn't solve the initial problem

Comment: The runtime cost is minimal, especially for something like FrameLayout. We do this in the Android framework for compound views like CalendarView and DatePickerView.

Comment: That's good to hear @alanv. Part of the solution would then be to use FrameLayout whenever possible. I've read somewhere that nested LinearLayouts are costly, but I guess FrameLayouts are cheap.